# How to use @Version in a @JoinTable

Tags: jpa, many-to-many, optimistic-locking

I am having an entity with a `@ManyToMany` relation:

```
@Audited(targetAuditMode = NOT_AUDITED)
@ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE}, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(
        name = "company_relationship",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "company_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "relationship_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
private Set<CompanyRelationshipLookup> companyRelationshipLookups = new HashSet<>();
```

I find it really handy to use `@JoinTable`, so the data is stored in my table company_relationship without providing an entity `CompanyRelation`. The table looks like this:

```
create table company_relationship
(
    company_id      bigint not null
        constraint company_relationship_company_id_fk
            references company,
    relationship_id bigint not null
        constraint company_relationship___fk
            references company_relationship_lookup,
    version         integer,
    constraint company_relationship_pk
        primary key (company_id, relationship_id)
);
```

In the db-table you can see the column `version`. Usually i would set `@Version` for optimistic locking in the entity, but as I don't want to implement a linking-entity each time and use `@ManyToMany` with `@JoinTable` instead.

Is there a way to do it? Or could this maybe be implemented in the future within @Jointable? I am using JPA 3.1.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: It cannot. If you want entity state you have to use an entity. It wouldn't make sense to have one in a JoinTable as it would only ever be 1 - these are either there or not there. A join table is an extension of the entity relationship, so the entity that owns it can have its version incremented when ever there is a change in the relationship, just as it would if you modify a OneToOne fk to point elsewhere.

Comment: You are totally right...I thought that the data could be manipulated from another point, but if I garantee that the data in the ManyToMany is only accessed over the the owning entity, I don't need the Version attribute within ManyToMany...thank you!